How to update/write DuckDB in production environment
Initial situation:
I use a DuckDB (file-based) as a data source for a Streamlit dashboard. The DuckDB is initially filled with data from a legacy database and should then receive new records from the legacy database every x minutes so that the Steamlit dashboard always has up-to-date data.
Problem:
DuckDB only allows either multiple read-only accesses (Streamlit) or exclusive write access.
Question:
What is the best way to update the DuckDB used by Streamlit without Streamlit users or the updater locking each other out?
Are there any best practices for my request?

Is the duckdb used by your app is common to all users?

I suggest you take a look at MotherDuck or, use threading which does work with multiple writers to a file DB
